ImportError: cannot import name 'Interpreter' from 'tensorflow.lite' \Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\__init__.py)
All of the init files in my tensorflow/lite directory are empty. Is there a git for the init.py files? I ma running version 2.16.1
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you!
I've reinstalled tf multiple times. I downloaded the tensorflow master-file to no avail.

From your question, I believe that you are having difficulty importing the Interpreter from the tensorflow.lite module.

Check the Correct Import Path:
You can now import Interpreter module from tflite_runtime instead of directly from the tensorflow module — due to sealed-off Python subdirectory rules.

 from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter



Ensure that you have installed the neccessary package. You can run this mate.

   pip install tflite-runtime


Additionally, you might need to install libatlas-base-dev using:
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

 # and possibly update your os environment especially if you are on Linux or Mac.


Ensure you created a virtualenv for the project you want to create, and not allow it to cluster your system.

For more information, check out it on tensorflow docs. Goodluck mate!

tensorflow/lite/__init__.py

Import any modules or classes that you want to make available when someone imports tensorflow.lite
For example, you might import specific classes from submodules:
from .interpreter import Interpreter

